# Existence of a non-trivial Homomorphism when the gcd of the group cardinalities is greater than 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that there does not exist a non-trivial homomorphism $\phi$ from $G_1$ to $G_2$ if $(|G_1|, |G_2|) = 1$ because there must exist an isomorphism $\mu$ between the quotient group $G_1/H$ and $\phi[G_1]$ by the Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem. Since $|G/H| | |G_1|$ (because the amount of cosets divides the order of the group) and $| \phi[G_1]| | |G_2|$ (because $\phi[G_1]$ is a subgroup of $G_2$), we find that $|G_1/H| = \phi[G_1] = 1$ is the only possibility when $(|G_1|, |G_2|) = 1$. Hence, there must be a trivial homomorphism in that case.

However, must there exist a homomorphism when $(|G_1|, |G_2|) = d > 1$? Is there any reliable way to prove when there does or does not exist a homomorphism when the gcd is greater than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible counterexample: there is no nontrivial homomorphism $S_3 \to \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$, despite the fact that $\gcd(|S_3|, |\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}|) = \gcd(6,3) = 3$.  (Outline of how I would prove it, though there might be more "elementary" solutions: since $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is Abelian, any such homomorphism would have to factor through the abelianization of $S_3$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.  But then, by the result that you quoted, there is no nontrivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: That makes sense thank you! Does this mean that there is no general way to disprove the existence of a homomorphism? In other words, is finding a homomorphism or using some technique to disprove the existence of a homomorphism the only way to show that there does exist a homomorphism?

Comment: That's right, as far as I know.  On the other hand, a general approach would should often help would be to take a presentation of the source group, and then look at what the relations imply about the images of the generators in the target group.  (So for example, $S_3$ has presentation $\langle \tau_1, \tau_2 \mid \tau_1^2 = \tau_2^2 = (\tau_1 \tau_2)^3 = 1 \rangle$ where $\tau_1$ represents $(1~2)$ and $\tau_2$ represents $(2~3)$, and then just the relations $\tau_1^2 = 1$ and $\tau_2^2 = 1$ imply the images of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ have to be trivial.)